# Javascript Dom selector HTml

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Can we refer to this `document.forms["contact-form"]["email"]`  without `["contact-form"]`just like this `document.forms["email"]` ?

Comment: No, but you can give it an ID, and use the much more appropriate `document.getElementById('email')`

Answer (score 0):

It would be most appropriate to assign an `ID` and use this:

`document.getElementByid('email');`

*Please do mark the answer if I helped. Happy Coding!*

Answer (score 0):

you can use either this code:

```
document.getElementByid('email');
```

or this one:

```
document.forms[0]["email"]
```